# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at native method calling

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, native

I created a DLL for testing purposes, as I need to load a DLL into a java wrapper class and use it's method. Everytime when I try to use a native Method, the following Exception appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  main.java.JNativeTest._Java_Sample1_intMethod(I)I
at main.java.JNativeTest._Java_Sample1_intMethod(Native Method)
at main.java.JNativeTest.main(JNativeTest.java:15)
```

I tried already to rename the methods to beginning with _ and also without leading _.

**Java Class**

```
public class JNativeTest {

public native int _Java_Sample1_intMethod(int n);
public native boolean _Java_Sample1_booleanMethod(boolean bool);
public native String stringMethod(String text);
public native int intArrayMethod(int[] intArray);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxx\\Desktop\\JNITest2.dll");
    JNativeTest testClass = new JNativeTest();
    int square = testClass._Java_Sample1_intMethod(5);
    boolean bool   =  testClass._Java_Sample1_booleanMethod(true);

    System.out.println("Int Methode: " + square);
    System.out.println("Boolean Methode: " + bool);
}

}
```

**CPP Class**

```
#include "main_java_JNativeTest.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample1_intMethod
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint num) {
       return num * num;

}
 JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_Sample1_booleanMethod
   (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jboolean boolean) {
       return !boolean;

}


 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Sample1_intArrayMethod
   (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jintArray array) {
         int i, sum = 0;
         jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(array);
         jint * body = env->GetIntArrayElements(array, 0);
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
             {    sum += body[i];
         }
     env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(array, body, 0);
     return sum;

}

void main() {}
```

**Header File**

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class main_java_JNativeTest */

#ifndef _Included_main_java_JNativeTest
#define _Included_main_java_JNativeTest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     main_java_JNativeTest
 * Method:    intMethod
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_main_java_JNativeTest_intMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

/*
 * Class:     main_java_JNativeTest
 * Method:    booleanMethod
 * Signature: (Z)Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_main_java_JNativeTest_booleanMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jboolean);

/*
 * Class:     main_java_JNativeTest
 * Method:    stringMethod
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_main_java_JNativeTest_stringMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     main_java_JNativeTest
 * Method:    intArrayMethod
 * Signature: ([I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_main_java_JNativeTest_intArrayMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jintArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

[Screenshot of Dependency Walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr9J4.png)

Id like to mention that I am very new to .NET/C++ and DLL's, I have only looked at it yesterday for work purposes - therefore I think that I maybe have some errors at the .cpp file or header file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your native methods in java should have different names (e.g. `intMethod` in package `Sample1`). [See this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html).

Comment: @Zereges thanks for your contribution. I read through your Link, but I think I could not conclude what is wrong with the naming. Now I changed the int Method _Java_Sample1_intMethod to Java_Sample1_intMethod and it produces nearly the exact same error.                                                               Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: main.java.JNativeTest.Java_Sample1_intMethod(I)I
 at main.java.JNativeTest.Java_Sample1_intMethod(Native Method)
 at main.java.JNativeTest.main(JNativeTest.java:15)

Comment: Don't touch names in Java. `javah/javac` will translate them into proper ones. Just write them as you want them to be. On the other hand, in `C/C++` pay attention to use proper names (as generated by `javac/javah`). Also, make sure to put your `dll` on `PATH` so it can be accessible. Alternatively, use `loadLibrary` and explicitly point to file with your shared library code. Also, take a look here for a very basic sample with description: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Comment: To rephrase what Oo.oO said ... the steps are: a) Write your method names in Java b) use `javac -h` to get a header file with the matching C method names c) don't touch any of the names, only define/fill in the methods in C. If you change anything in the Java native methods, i.e the method name or the class name or the package name, regenerate the C header files and change your method definitions to match.